# JavaFX issue with MediaPlayer.seek() and MediaPlayer.getCurrentTime();

Tags: java, audio, javafx

I'm playing a mp3 file with JavaFX's MediaPlayer, and the `getCurrentTime()` works fine, but when I use at some point the `seek()` method, the `getCurrentTime()` returns the wrong time. Is this a JavaFX issue?

Comment: Dude, I have your same issue. I thought I was going crazy.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a small example w.r.t your issue and everything works fine. `seek()` works fine, so as the `getCurrentTime()` **before** and **after** `seek()`. Have a look at this example

```
import java.io.File;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;


public class MediaPlayerMP3 extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage arg0) throws Exception {
        String source = new File("audio.mp3").toURI().toString();
        Media media = null;
        media = new Media(source);
        final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
        mediaPlayer.play();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true)
                {
                    if(mediaPlayer.getCurrentTime().greaterThan(Duration.millis(1000)) 
                            && mediaPlayer.getCurrentTime().lessThan(Duration.millis(3000)))
                        mediaPlayer.seek(Duration.millis(80000));
                    System.out.println(mediaPlayer.getCurrentTime());
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```